# Storing a hexadecimal string without using arrays in C

Tags: c, string, hex

Our school gave us an assignment and in some part of that assignment we are supposed to take a hexadecimal input then convert it to binary. But the problem is that using arrays are not permitted. When using an array to store the hexadecimal string I can easily convert it to binary but is there anyway to store it without using arrays?

Comment: dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: When someone is telling me "take hexadecimal and convert to binary" I am getting really suspicious that actually nothing needs to be done here. So please, describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: what we need to do is get a hexadecimal input from the user and convert it to binary letter by letter then use that binary for a XOR operation. I am quite new to C so to do that operation I feel like I need to assign those binary numbers to a variable to use it in a future operation.

Comment: Is there a "binary" somewhere in the input or output? If not, this conversion step is most likely unnecessary. Computer can perform binary operations on *numbers* regardless of their representation to the user. What is your input? What is your required output?

Comment: our assignment says that we must take hexadecimal input from the user, conver it to binary, and use that binary for encryption with XOR logic(a key is selected prior to this operation). But xor operation provided in the C is also not permitted to use. So I need to do the conversion in order to pass it to the encryption.

Comment: No arrays yet required to convert data to a bit-stream? Hm. There must be some misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: I need to access each letter or digit of the input one by one so don't I need to use an array for that? I'm sorry if I am not clear enough, I am way too new to C :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with C, most languages have the concept of arrays. An array is an indexed "collection" of equally typed elements. Any string is an array. -- Please show us some source code how you are supposed to do the encryption.

Comment: They didn't provide any source code but I can send you the assignment explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task seems to be:

> Convert input data entered as hexadecimal values to a stream of binary digits.

You can just read the input ne byte at a time and convert any hexadecimal character to the corresponding binary digits.

There are many different ways to approach this problem, here is an implementation with a `switch` statement.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
          case '0': fputs("0000", stdout); break;
          case '1': fputs("0001", stdout); break;
          case '2': fputs("0010", stdout); break;
          case '3': fputs("0011", stdout); break;
          case '4': fputs("0100", stdout); break;
          case '5': fputs("0101", stdout); break;
          case '6': fputs("0110", stdout); break;
          case '7': fputs("0111", stdout); break;
          case '8': fputs("1000", stdout); break;
          case '9': fputs("1001", stdout); break;
          case 'A':
          case 'a': fputs("1010", stdout); break;
          case 'B':
          case 'b': fputs("1011", stdout); break;
          case 'C':
          case 'c': fputs("1100", stdout); break;
          case 'D':
          case 'd': fputs("1101", stdout); break;
          case 'E':
          case 'e': fputs("1110", stdout); break;
          case 'F':
          case 'f': fputs("1111", stdout); break;
          case '\n':
          case ' ': putchar(c); break;
          default:  break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you just need to read a value encoded as a hexadecimal string and store it into a variable, `scanf()` is a simple solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary(unsigned int x) {
    if (x > 1) {
        print_binary(x >> 1);
    }
    putchar('0' + (x & 1));
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned int value;

    if (scanf("%x", &value) == 1) {
        print_binary(value);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what i needed but the only thing is, i actually need to store the printed binary value in a variable.

Comment: So you need to read a value encoded in hexadecimal, store it in binary into a variable? Do you need to print the value in binary or just store the value?

Comment: i just need to store the binary value

Comment: @STT: OK, no need to *convert it to binary.* then. You just want to convert to an integer. Numbers are indeed stored in memory as binary, but the conversion is independent of the internal representation. When you mention *convert it to binary.* many programmers will assume you want to output a binary representation.

Comment: thanks a lot. I can work my way through the second code. I understand the confusion. I will be more careful from now on :)